# How to initialize `std::set` in constructor parameter?

Tags: c++, constructor, initializer-list, stdset, enum-class

I have a construction that takes a `std::set` as a parameter.
How do I initialize the set in the constructor parameter?

Here's an minimal conceptual example.  Actual implementation is much larger.

```
#include <set>

enum class Fruits
{
    APPLE, PEACH, BANANA, STRAWBERRY, LEMON
};

class Pie
{
public:
    Pie(const std::set<Fruits>& flavors)
        : m_flavors(flavors)
    {
    }

    std::set<Fruits> m_flavors;
};

int main()
{
    // What is syntax for initialization here?
    Pie p(std::set<Fruits> {Fruits::APPLE, Fruits::BANANA});

    return 0;
}
```

The objective is to be able to specify the values for `set` on the parameter list.

In pseudo code:

```
Pie p({Fruits::APPLE, Fruits::BANANA});
```

The above would have the effect of passing a `std::set`, initialized with `APPLE, BANANA`, to the constructor of `class Pie`.

This concept would be used in the following snippet:

```
class Fruit_Pie
: public Pie
{
  Fruit_Pie()
    : Pie(/* wish: {Fruits::APPLE, Fruits::LEMON}*/)
    { ; }
};
```

In the above snippet, creating an instance of `std::set<Fruits>` before calling the constructor is not practical.  If there is a method to do this, I'm open for it.

*Research:*
Searching the internet resulted in examples about initializing an instance of an `std::set` as a separate statement, not parameter initialization.

My previous attempt at this concept was to use `unsigned int` and bitwise OR the values in the initializer list.  I was "upgrading" to use an `std::set`.

*Environment:*
Compiler: Visual Studio 2017
Platform: Windows 10 and Windows 7

Comment: Did you take a closer look at initializer lists?

Comment: There is a constructor for set that takes an initializer list, can you give us the error message you get when using `Pie p(std::set<Fruits> {Fruits::APPLE, Fruits::BANANA});`? VS 2017 is a C++11 compiler, so it should have worked.

Comment: "in the above snippet, creating an instance of std::set<Fruits> before calling the constructor is not practical. If there is a method to do this."  didnt get the statement.

Comment: @GilsonPJ:  In a constructor, how does one create a temporary variable within the constructor list (or before the constructor is called).  This is what I'm indicating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pseudocode is valid C++11 - it is calling the `std::initializer_list` constructor overload of `std::set`. [**live example on wandbox.org**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/8TFTqyVoize91zcW)